# gulp: How can i check if files has changed?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to check if JS changed so I can bump their version.

For now, I use a JSON file with JS version and CSS version and I update this file every time the build task is running.

it looks ~

```
const JEDITOR = require( 'edit-json-file' );
const THEME_VERSION = new Date( ).toJSON( ).slice( 0, 10 ).replace( /-/g, '' );
const VERSION_FILE = JEDITOR( 'package.version.json' );

GULP.task( 'scripts-min', function ( ) {
...
VERSION_FILE.set( 'theme_js_version', THEME_VERSION );
VERSION_FILE.save( );
...
} );
```

I want to update this file only if something has changed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try gulp-rev and read this https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev#different-hash-for-unchanged-files

Comment: Or try gulp.watch.